# Maker is not drawing after updating lat long in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, navigator

I am using http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/ for google map but the marker is drawing only at the first time. If I update the lat-long then the only map is shifting not the marker.

Here is my code : (Current Location)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      vm.latitude_obj=position.coords.latitude;
      vm.longitude_obj=position.coords.longitude;
    });
          vm.map={center: {latitude: '28.454035292774627', longitude: '77.02379857578137' }, zoom: 12 };
          vm.options={scrollwheel: false};
          vm.marker = {
              id: 0,
              coords: {
                  latitude: 28.454035292774627,
                  longitude: 77.02379857578137
              },
              options: { draggable: true },
              events: {
                  dragend: function (marker, eventName, args) {
                      var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                      var lon = marker.getPosition().lng();
                      }
                  }
              };
```

After updating Location :

```
vm.map = {center: {latitude: vm.latitude_obj, longitude: vm.longitude_obj }, zoom: 12 };
            vm.options = {scrollwheel: false};
            vm.marker = {
            id: 0,
            coords: {
                latitude: vm.latitude_obj,
                longitude: vm.longitude_obj
            },
            options: { draggable: true },
            events: {
                dragend: function (marker, eventName, args) {
                    vm.lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                    vm.lon = marker.getPosition().lng();
                    $scope.vm.listingModal.latitude=vm.lat;
                    $scope.vm.listingModal.longitude=vm.lon;
                    vm.locationSelected='Location Changed to '+vm.lat+', '+vm.lon;
                }
            }
            };
```

In this code map is moving from current location to new location but marker is not.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

upon updating your lat and lng set the marker's position

```
marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
```

where myLatlng is an object of format

```
myLatlng = {lat: latitude_value, lng: longitude_value}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details or send me some link where I can find the details information on it